# IOT rak button unable to connect to dragino gateway through lorawan

Tags: connection, gateway, network-protocols, iot

i have this iot button brand RAK lorabutton, and i'm trying to connect it to a dragino gateway through lorawan protocol in order to connect it to a theInternetOfThings server.

but the problem is that when i execute the join with the sentence "at+join=otaa" the result is

OK
Join OTAA...
Fail

this is something the button answer since it couldn't conect.

now i checked and we are on the same frequency,Spreading Factor,Coding Rate and Signal Bandwidth. so it doesn't look like a configuration problem. 
every bit of is welcomed